# How to properly use gcc -fsso-struct for portable programs?

Tags: c, gcc, portability, endianness, bit-fields

I am trying to use gcc option -fsso-struct to set portably bit-fields layouts (I think it is a gcc-6 features https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html).

Currently, I have two sets of bit-fields structures : one for big endian and one for little endian. I use the BYTE_ORDER flag to choose one or the other (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html).

I set alternatively -fsso-struct to big and little endian but I don't see the difference in interpreting the bit-fields. How should I use it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the warning in the documentation:

> **Warning:** the `-fsso-struct` switch causes GCC to generate code that is not binary compatible with code generated without it if the specified endianness is not the native endianness of the target.

Any option with such a warning is an option that you should not be using if you're interacting with any library, even the standard library.

---

This option is also available in a local form, which can be used safely through a `#pragma` directive. These functions:

```
struct A { int i; };
#pragma scalar_storage_order big-endian
struct B { int i; };
#pragma scalar_storage_order little-endian
struct C { int i; };
#pragma scalar_storage_order default
struct D { int i; };

int fa(struct A a) { return a.i; }
int fb(struct B b) { return b.i; }
int fc(struct C c) { return c.i; }
int fd(struct D d) { return d.i; }
```

cause `struct A` and `struct D` to have the platform's default endianness, `struct B` to be big endian, and `struct C` to be little endian. As a result, `fa`, `fd`, and either `fb` or `fc`, can be compiled to code that simply loads the value directly from the parameter. The remaining function, either `fc` or `fb`, will contain code to swap the bytes.

As you can see, this option is not about bit-fields. It does affect bit-fields too, but that's only because bit-fields store integer values, and this option affects integer storage.

Comment: I saw the warning but I did not understand it. I'm still not sure I do :D What can it be used for ? Okay for the second part and the note on bit-fields. Going back to my main issue which is having to sets of structures, I could use the adequat #pragma in a test on BYTE_ORDER ?

Comment: No, the idea is that for structure types that must be portable between big- and little-endian systems, you specify the same endianness. If one system stores my `struct B` or `struct C`, and another reads it, then as long as they agree on the size of `int`, they will agree on the value being transferred.

Comment: Oh I see ! Both systems will store in the requested endianness independently of their own.